# Push Notifications - Subscribed devices w/ tokens using certificates not delivering Push on iOS

Tags: ios, titanium, apple-push-notifications, ssl-certificate, appcelerator

Apple no longer provides separate Push Notification SSL certificates for Production and Development Apps.

Which may be causing Push Notification failures to newly submitted apps on the app store using the Appcelerator Platform

Instead Apple now provide the following 2 certificates:

1. "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox)" - **works in
   development**
2. "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox &
   Production)" - **works in development** *But not in Production*

[Please see the certificates selection on the Apple Developer center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfnWl.png)

The Certificate's are no longer listed as:

**APNs Developement iOS** or **APNs Production iOS**

but NOW instead simply as **Apple Push Notification**

[The new listing of APN certificates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XDvm.png)

These certificates installed and exported from my keychain as .p12 and uploaded and saved to my Appcelerator Platform as usual.

### **In Development**

Push works as expected

### **In Production** (ad Hoc or App Store Submissions)

Device registers to Push and retrieves a device token.

This is confirmed in the Appcelerator Platform

This is also confirmed on the device's APSD logs which are observed by downloading and installing *PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig* on the device

This shows:

- The device is enabled to receive Push from my bundle ID
- The Device receives a device Token

When sending a simple Push Notification using Appcelerator Platform, the Success status is returned for all iOS devices (in test only one used)

However, no push notification is seen on the device (multiple devices tested).

I can see both Parse and Urban Airship have made some changes since Apple's change (Late Dec 2015)

Existing apps seem to have no problem.  Only new Production Apps using the new Apple Push Notification Certificate seem to have an issue :(

The app code is working, and correct as Push is successfully delivered in Development for iOS, Android is working too.

I have also deleted and recreated provisioning profiles and push certificates to check configuration.

**Anyone else seeing this issue too or am I going mad :)?**

*First Post here so please be gentle :) I have given my best effort to check for similar questions/answers and to give you guys the most info I can give.. any pointers to better frame the above are most welcome.*

Comment: Did you upload the p12 in the produciton tab for the Arrow Push in the Dashboard? There are two separate tabs for development and production.

Comment: Thank you @Soumya for responding.  Yes I have added it under Production, and it didnt work.  The same certificate I also added under Development (simply to test), as the new production certificate can be used for both production and sandbox.  Under development it worked, however when i used it for production it did not :(

Comment: Ok, I might be asking too many questions, but I too want to solve it because I also need to implement Push Notification for one of my upcoming project. Can you tell me the Appcelerator SDK that you are using and the version of the cloud module (see in tiapp.xml)

Comment: no problem please ask as many questions as you like, it may help me too!! @soumya I am using ti.cloud 3.2.9 and SDK 4.0.0.GA.  You should also be able to test this by packaging an Ad Hoc ipa for your registered apple device, and send push notifications under **production** tab in Appcelerator Platform.  You will see the device registered, and you will also see the status of push notification as **success** yet, the Push will not be actually delivered :(

Comment: I have raised a JIRA ticket on the advice of appcelerator.  please watch here: https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/AC-691

Comment: Added a watch to the ticket